# decorator to track number function calls - not working

Tags: python, debugging, decorator

Why does the `count_calls_bad` version not retain the added function attribute (decorator adds `.calls` to the passed in func) after it returns? I understand the second (good) version is binding inside of the inner function versus the bad version which tries to create a closure where the func attribute is bound, but I thought that the "bad" version would maintain reference to the  closed over variable, allowing me to get the same result as the "good" version.

```
   def count_calls_bad(func):
        func.calls = 0 
        def inner(*args,**kwargs):
            func.calls += 1 #each call to inner increments func.calls (recur_n.calls)
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return inner

   def count_calls_good(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        inner.calls += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    inner.calls = 0
    return inner

    @count_calls_bad
    def recur_n(num):
        if num == 0:
            return 0
        print (num)
        return recur_n(num-1)

    recur_n(10)
    print(recur_n.calls) #recur_n.calls attribute not bound any longer
```

**UPDATE**: fixed code, forgot to update function name after testing in editor.  Now recur_n is called and not recur_10.

---

Additionally, I  was playing around and think that the issue is recur_n becomes `inner`, and then that last line `print(recur_n.calls)` is really `print(function count_calls_bad.<locals>.inner at 0x000000000364E2F0>)`, and that object has no attribute `calls`, since calls was bound on the actual undecorated `recur_n`.

You can actually force your way into the original undecorated function and get the correctly updated attribute with the following hackery:

`print(recur_n.__closure__[0].cell_contents.calls)`

My next thought was then to use functools @wraps to maintain the original undecorated function name, since that is basically what I'm doing above, reaching into the decorator and pulling out the undecorated name's `call` attribute.

```
from functools import wraps
       def count_calls_bad(func):
            func.calls = 0
            @wraps func 
            def inner(*args,**kwargs):
                func.calls += 1 #each call to inner increments func.calls (recur_n.calls)
                return func(*args,**kwargs)
            return inner
```

This at least gets me a result, but that result is zero. So now, I've answered my own original question, but I end up with a new one.  Why, given that @wraps has updated the function so that recur_n, now refers to recur_n rather than inner, do I get 0 rather than 11?

It appears that @wraps copies the signature of the function, but does not maintain reference or copy other data such as variables or attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, the reason you can't see the count is because the `recur_n` name at the top level of your module refers to the wrapper function `inner` returned from the decorator. It doesn't refer to the original `recur_n` function (though you can get access to that function via the `__closure__` attribute of the wrapper function).

Using `functools.wraps` doesn't change that basic issue. All it does is copy some of the attributes of the original function onto the wrapper function. So the `recur_n` function you see at the top level will have its `__name__` set to `"recur_n"` rather than `"inner"` and it's `__doc__` would match the original `recur_n`'s docstring (if it had one). The `wraps` call also copies the current values of any attributes in the function's `__dict__` to the new wrapper function.

Setting the function's `__name__` doesn't change what the name refers to in the module namespace. Indeed, after using `wraps`, both functions (the original `recur_n` and the wrapper function) will have the same `__name__` attribute, `"recur_n"`. The module can only have one thing referenced by the name `recur_n` and it could be either one of them or something completely different!

As for why you see `0` when you check `recur_n.calls` when you are using `wraps` in the decorator, that's because the zero got copied over as part of the `__dict__` of the original function. You can't see the incremented count though, since the copy only happened once (and Python integers are immutable, so they can't be updated in place).

Answer (score 1):

You never defined `recur_n`, at least not in the posted code.  You applied the decorator to `recur_10`.